# LVM snapshot of MyISAM tables requires repair every time

Tags: replication, mariadb, myisam, snapshot-replication

I'm attempting to setup slave replication of a large MyISAM table. I login to the master server and perform `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SHOW MASTER STATUS` and that returns right away with the position and file. I then take a LVM snapshot, and then issue `UNLOCK TABLES` (note: I do this in the same mysql prompt, I do not exit). As far as I know, this is the correct way to do this.

I then rsync the snapshot to my new system, set the permissions and start up mariadb, almost immediately it says, "Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables and aria-recover for all Aria tables" and then I look at the processlist for this server and I see that it is doing a 'Repair by sorting' on this table.

Why is this table being repaired, if the tables were originally flushed? Is it possible that the high number of queries and size of the database means that the operating system has not yet flushed the blocks to disk, because it has a lot of dirty buffers, yet still returns me to the command line for the `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` command?

I would like to be able to avoid the `repair table`, because it takes a day and half to complete, but I don't understand why there is a file descriptor difference in the MYD making mariadb decide it needs to repair. The only way I can think of to be sure there is no difference would be to shutdown completely the master's mariadb process, and then do the lvmsnapshot, however then I cannot get the results of a `SHOW MASTER STATUS` to setup the replication.

Can someone please tell me how to solve this (also, please don't tell me to move off of MyISAM, believe me I would if I was allowed to).

I decided to try it a second time, and do a `myisamchk --update-state --myisam_sort_buffer_size=8G --key_buffer_size=8G --read_buffer_size=1024M --write_buffer_size=1024M /var/lib/mysql/db/store.MYI` to see if I could tell why it thinks it needs to repair, and it says this:

```
Data records: 365221349   Deleted blocks:  266143
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
- check file-size
- check record delete-chain
myisamchk: warning: Found 34585232 deleted space in delete link chain. Should be 34630096
myisamchk: error: Found 265707 deleted rows in delete link chain. Should be 266143
myisamchk: error: record delete-link-chain corrupted
- check key delete-chain
- check index reference
- check data record references index: 1
- check record links
34600000
```

and that counter is increasing, I have no idea where it is trying to get to, but I suspect this will take many hours.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you still using MyISAM for this table? InnoDB has crash recovery, and many other advantages. InnoDB has better performance than MyISAM too.

Comment: If I had a choice to migrate it, I would, but the migration to InnoDB would take a significant amount of downtime, on a live instance that doesn't have that kind of window for an outage.

Comment: I've used [pt-online-schema-change](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html) to perform many types of table alterations with nearly no downtime. Alterations in production, during peak hours, any day of week, any time of day.

Comment: Another strategy is to create a replica MySQL Server, do the alteration on the replica, and then do a quick switch so the replica becomes the new primary database server.

Comment: Yea, this is exactly what I have been proposing we do, do the replica migration to InnoDB, and then switch. However, I'm blocked by people saying that they are worried that once the InnoDB version is online, it may potentially have degraded performance, and they want to determine that ahead of time.

Comment: Regarding pt-online-schema-change, thanks for that suggestion. However, this database table is over 200gb in size, and pt-online-schema-change makes a copy of the table in order to do the alteration, if it only needed another 200gb to do the operation then that is doable, butthe actual end space requirements are not documented in the tool. Also, this database is heavily written to, I'd be concerned that the conversion may not be able to ever catch up with the changes and be infinitely converting.

Comment: I definitely recommend using this tool on smaller, less important tables first, until you become confident with using it. I'd recommend the same advice with any other tool that is new to you.

Comment: By the way, using ALTER TABLE also creates a copy table, so you need extra space to use it. Regarding the catching up, pt-online-schema-change keeps the original table and the copy table in sync continuously while it's running, by using triggers to repeat every change to the original table.

Comment: The bottom line is that you need to find one way or another to perform alterations to this table that suits your business needs. Being afraid to alter it ever again is not going to be a supportable strategy, because I assume the table is only going to get larger.

Comment: I couldn't agree more about being afraid to alter it ever. If it were up to me, I would have done this a long time ago, but unfortunately, the fear resides in the person who makes the decision here. Fortunately, I've managed to convince them to let me do the replication ALTER TABLE method to a development environment so we can see how it goes and simulate it.

Comment: FYI, in addition to needing extra storage space for the copy table, pt-online-schema-change needs a lot of space for binary logs during the transition. Proportional to the `data_length` of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem appears to be related to the high number of writes happening, and the speed which I performed the snapshot immediately after doing the `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`. I tried it several more times, and it kept needing repairs.

When I issued the `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` and then opened another terminal, and issued the age old unix magic trick (one I thought was no longer necessary and just a NOOP now days): `sync; sync; sync`. Then I did the snapshot. This snapshot worked.

Obviously, MyISM is the problem here, and I received many helpful comments about moving to InnoDB, which clearly needs to happen, and I'm hopeful I can convince the right people that it is what needs to be done.